# How to pull data from an external source (REST API) with Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, rest, dbms-scheduler, dbms-job

I'm evaluating the possibility of pulling XML data from an external service (REST API) over the internet by using Oracle SQL DBMS_Scheduler. This would ideally be an automated solution running on the database server. Is this technically possible and what would be the recommended way for implementation?

Traditionally to have such process automated, I would need a dedicated server that pulls data from the external service and pushes that data further into SQL tables.

I'm trying to come up with a solution where the dedicated server is replaced with DBMS_Scheduler or similar, and the data would be pulled directly into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a REST service from PL/SQL making an HTTP POST request using UTL_HTTP, then you can add the procedure to DBMS_SCHEDULER.